# Change "modal" to something like Jquery "toggle"?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal that pops up with some information when clicked, here is how it looks:

```
<a rel="moodalbox 850 300 nofollow" href="<?php echo $infolink;?>"
```

where **$infolink** is given a LINK to some page.

So what I want to ask, is it possible somehow to open this NOT in a modalbox like now, but just the information to appear in the site somewhere(no page re-loading)...?
Please can somebody just give me a HINT please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preventDefault()` method:

```
$('a[rel*="moodalbox"]').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault()
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#info').text(href)
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z6XF/)